# Wordpress, how to create a user and fill additional fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a register page in my Wordpress site.
I have extra fields in the database which I want to fill when the user is created - they are predetermined:

```
showbusiness = 1 
showemail = 1 
showaddress = 1 
showphone = 1 
showwebsite = 1 
showemailcontent =1
```

How would I go about adding these as I currently have this below but I know `wp_create_user` doesnt allow this:

```
$status = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
```

Comment: I recommend you to stop the coding. Look at this: https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-registration-form-builder-with-submission-manager/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the necessary columns already exist at one of the tables:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'registration_extra_fields', 10, 1 );

function registration_extra_fields( $user_id ) {

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'users'; // or any other table

    $wpdb->get_results("
        UPDATE $table_name
        SET column = val
        WHERE ID = $user_id
    ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress wrapper function you want to use is `update_user_meta()`. You can also use `add_user_meta()` but update will add it there if it doesn't exist.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'registration_extra_fields', 10, 1 );
function registration_extra_fields( $user_id ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'showbusiness', 1);
    /* repeat for each data value */
}
```

Note to trigger the action 'user_register' used by Faisal and I you will need to use the `wp_insert_user()` function. This is similar to `wp_create_user()` function but allows for a larger range of input.

Also note that you can send entire arrays to the usermeta table, not just single values. This can help speed up operations.

so something like this could be used within the hook function:

```
$data = array(
    'showbusiness' => 1, 
    'showemail' => 1,
    'showaddress' => 1,
    'showphone' => 1,
    'showwebsite' => 1,
    'showemailcontent' => 1
)
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'showflags', $data );
```

Then where you need to use the data you use `get_user_meta( $user_id, 'showflags');`

Hope that helps.